# AND doesn't work in Conditional Formatting/ Custom Formula

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a Custom Formula using Google Sheet's conditional formatting feature. When 2 things are TRUE, I want to change background and font color somehow.

I use the following statement to determine it `=AND(F5:F10>30% ,$B$1 =True)`

This works well and is tested independently, row by row.

Yet, when applied to the table only some columns are highlighted, not all

[image]

Below is a formula I am using
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
=($F5>30%)*($B$1=TRUE)
```